# FileNotFoundException..Classpath resource not found in spring?

Tags: spring

I have code like this in ***Main.java*** :

```
AbstractApplicationContext context  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

Until recently it was working, but I don't know why it started failing with the below exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from
>   class path resource
>   [spring-config.xml]; nested exception
>   is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   class path resource
>   [spring-config.xml] cannot be opened
>   because it does not exist

the ***spring-config.xml*** is in ***src/main/resources*** folder.

Actually I wanted to learn about the annotations: @Postconstruct and @Predestroy, so I changed the build path to Jdk 1.6 from Jdk 1.5.

Since then the problem started...

Any clue why it is not working?

NOTE: If any wants to see my project structure please follow this link
[http://code.google.com/p/javapracticeram/source/browse/trunk/SpringExample/](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javapracticeram/source)

EDIT: [image]

Answer (score 11):

Looking at [your classpath](http://code.google.com/p/javapracticeram/source/browse/trunk/SpringExample/.classpath#) you exclude `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`:

```
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
```

Is there a reason for it? Try not to exclude a classpath to `spring-config.xml` :)

Answer (score 3):

Check the contents of SpringExample/target/classes.  Is spring-config.xml there?  If not, try manually removing the SpringExample/target/ directory, and force a rebuild with Project=>Clean... in Eclipse.

Comment: can you please elaborate on why this happen's. After a lot of debugging this issue, i stumbled upon your answer but i still can not understand the reason for this issue.

Comment: Based on the Java Build Path configuration in the above screenshot, Eclipse dumps compiled classes (plus anything else from the classpath, including .xml files) into target/classes.  Depending on what other build tools are in use (Maven, Ant, sbt, etc.), something might be erasing that directory outside the knowledge of Eclipse, and forcing a Clean in Eclipse will make sure that target/classes gets rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to spring-config.xml is not in classpath.

Add complete path of spring-config.xml to your classpath.

Also write command you execute to run your project. You can check classpath in command.

Comment: Yok,Thanks for your reply..As i mentioned in the question config file is in Resources folder which is in the build path(please see the screen shot)..

How i run my project is i just run the main.jav file..and my project starts...

Could you please be more specific about what u r suggesting..I could not understand..

Thanks for your reply..

Comment: @javanerd Build Path won't be used to run your program. can you also put screenshot for  Run configuration you use. I assume you are running your program from eclipse.

Comment: I dont know what i did but it is working now...

Thanks YoK for looking into my question[silly] :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things worth pointing out:

1. The scope of your spring-context dependency shouldn't be "runtime", but "compile", which is the default, so you can just remove the scope line.
2. You should configure the compiler plugin to compile to at least java 1.5 to handle the annotations when building with Maven. (Can also affect IDE settings, though Eclipse doesn't tend to care.)

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.5</source>
                   <target>1.5</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

After that, reconfiguring your project from Maven should fix it. I don't recall exactly how to do that in Eclipse, but you should find it if you right click the project node and poke around the menus.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem when running my project. On checking the files structure, I realised that Spring's xml file was inside the project's package  and  thus couldn't be found. I put it outside the package and it worked just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Best way to handle such error-"**Use Annotation**".
spring.xml-`<context:component-scan base-package=com.SpringCollection.SpringCollection"/>`

add annotation in that class for which you want to use Bean ID(i am using class  "First")-

```
@Component
```

public class First {

Changes In Main Class**-

> **ApplicationContext context = 
>               new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(First.class);**
>   use this.